# Pagination for custom post type in Wordpress not working?

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

code for pagination in custom type posts

```
<?php  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; // For pagination

$loop = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'Portfolio','posts_per_page' => 3,'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
'paged'=>$paged ) ); ?> //For implementing pagination
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()): ?>
<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?> <div id="latestproimg">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array('title' => false)); ?></a>
</div>
<div id="latestpostser">
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></h2> //displaying the title
<?php //echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php //the_content( 'Read the full post »' ); ?> // for displaying the content
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Please tell me where is the mistake in code

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this weird pagination problem even though I already put the $page option but heres what solved my problem try to change the **paged** parameter into **page** of your get_query_var function

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; // For pagination
```

let me know if it works

Comment: This worked for me a couple of months ago, also I had to rename the object that is storing the query to "$the_query" for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

`get_query_var('paged')` doesn't work if the permalinks setting changes the url to something like `http://domain.com/page/2/...`. So, a more flexible version of @IoQ's answer would be,

```
$search_values['paged'] = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged')
: ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
```

This works if either permalinks is set to something like postname OR `paged=xx` is part of the url